# Debian redirect subdomain to virtualhosts

Tags: debian, virtualhost, redirect

I am very new to server stuff so please be gentle..
I would like that sub.mydomain.com (from OVH) bring users to http://[ip_address]/~username/ (from KS)

In my registrar, I added A type redirection to [ip_address]

/etc/apache2/sites-available/username is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin postmaster@mydomain.com
        ServerName www.sub.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias sub.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/
        <Directory /home/username/public_html/>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /home/username/logs/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /home/username/logs/access.log combined
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is sub.mydomain.com redirect to /var/www/html/ instead of /home/username/public_html/
Also, I do have userdir.

I am stuck from here. How can I do the trick? Thanks for your help.

**SOLUTION:** /etc/apache2/sites-available/username :  **username** must be **username.conf**

Comment: What is the url of the sub domain to determin which user path should be taken ?

Comment: I'm sad that even that I do not understand. What does it mean?

Comment: username is dynamic ? sub.mydomain.com is static, so how you get the username ? username.domain.com or sub.domain.com/username ?

Comment: I don't know if it is dynamic, I just used `useradd -g www-data -m username` , created sites-available/username with the configuration I gave. Finished with adding it to /sites-enabled/

Comment: The solution does not redirect an user from a domain to an other

Comment: so I have no idea why but it does work for me...

Comment: It is the your DNS configuration who make the redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can basicaly redirect the trafic:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/
        Redirect permanent / http://[ip_address]/~username/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Any Apache config files, have to be named `.conf` to be used